# Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher

Tags: ios, ios7

I've been trying to find some information regarding the new multitasking switcher in iOS 7 and especially the screenshot that the OS takes when the app is going into hibernation.

[image]

Is there any way to completely turn off this feature or screenshot? Or can I hide the app altogether from the switcher? The app needs to run in the background, but we do not want to show any screenshot from the app.

The screenshot is potentially a security-risk, think along the lines for banking-apps where your card number or account summary will be available to anyone that double-click on the home button on the device.

Anyone with any insight into this? Thanks.

Comment: My current solution is to load blank view with the app logo once the app enters hibernation and remove it when the app returns, but that solution is hard to manage and seems like a hack rather than an elegant solution.

Also, this solution fails from time to time depending on device etc. So it's not really a usable one.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In [Preparing Your UI to Run in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background), Apple says:

> #### Prepare Your UI for the App Snapshot
>
> At some point after your app enters the background and your delegate method returns, UIKit takes a snapshot of your app’s current user interface. The system displays the resulting image in the app switcher. It also displays the image temporarily when bringing your app back to the foreground.
>
> Your app’s UI must not contain any sensitive user information, such as passwords or credit card numbers. If your interface contains such information, remove it from your views when entering the background. Also, dismiss alerts, temporary interfaces, and system view controllers that obscure your app’s content. The snapshot represents your app’s interface and should be recognizable to users. When your app returns to the foreground, you can restore data and views as appropriate.

See [Technical Q&A QA1838: Preventing Sensitive Information From Appearing In The Task Switcher](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html)

In addition to obscuring/replacing sensitive information, you might also want to tell iOS 7 to not take the screen snapshot via [`ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623097-ignoresnapshotonnextapplicationl), whose documentation says:

> If you feel that the snapshot cannot correctly reflect your app’s user interface when your app is relaunched, you can call `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` to prevent that snapshot image from being taken.

Having said that, it appears that the screen snapshot is still taken and I have therefore filed a bug report. But you should test further and see if using this setting helps.

If this was an enterprise app, you might also want to look into the appropriate setting of `allowScreenShot` outlined in the [Restrictions Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13) section of the *Configuration Profile Reference.*

---

Here is an implementation that achieves what I needed. You can present your own `UIImageView`, or your can use a delegate-protocol pattern to obscure the confidential information:

```
//  SecureDelegate.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SecureDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)hide:(id)object;
- (void)show:(id)object;

@end
```

I then gave my app delegate a property for that:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SecureDelegate> secureDelegate;
```

My view controller sets it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.secureDelegate = self;
}
```

The view controller obviously implements that protocol:

```
- (void)hide:(id)object
{
    self.passwordLabel.alpha = 0.0;
}

- (void)show:(id)object
{
    self.passwordLabel.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

And, finally, my app delegate avails itself of this protocol and property:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch];  // this doesn't appear to work, whether called here or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but seems prudent to include it

    [self.secureDelegate hide:@"applicationWillResignActive:"];  // you don't need to pass the "object", but it was useful during my testing...
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.secureDelegate show:@"applicationDidBecomeActive:"];
}
```

Note, I'm using `applicationWillResignActive` rather than the advised `applicationDidEnterBackground`, because, as others have pointed out, the latter is not called when double tapping on the home button while the app is running.

I wish I could use notifications to handle all of this, rather than the delegate-protocol pattern, but in my limited testing, the notifications aren't handled in a timely-enough manner, but the above pattern works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Rob, your document-digging-fu is better than mine :) Still, we went a slightly different route as we never got ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch to work. It could possibly be regarding the bug-report you filed with apple. Would you mind sharing your example-code with us? At least so we have something to compare to. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that, as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937313/unable-to-update-view-when-app-goes-into-background-in-ios-7-using-applicationdi the behaviour is not always the same in the simulator as on the device!

Comment: @Rob You hid confidential information in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method?. but how about from foreground and user tap home button 2x, and multitasking shows. my app didn't go to background yet, hence `applicationDidEnterBackground` & `applicationWillResignActive` don't get called.

Comment: @HelmiB Hmm. In my test, if you double tap the home button while the app is running, `applicationDidEnterBackground` is not called, but `applicationWillResignActive` is (testing on both iOS 7.0.3 device and simulator). Are you sure you're not seeing `applicationWillResignActive` called?

Comment: @Rob, ops, my bad. Dunno what's wrong, it seems working now. million thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, the `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` method is ignored if it is not invoked during state restoration, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html).

Comment: You don't need to do it in applicationWillResignActive because the screenshot isn't taken until applicationDidEnterBackground.  When you double-tap the home button, no screen shot is taken; the screen you are seeing is live.  Add an animation to your screen to verify, e.g. cycle background colors.  If you then pick another app, your applicationDidEnterBackground will get called before the actual screenshot is taken.

Comment: +1 for your good answer.
Nevertheless, using Notifications by observing the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` did the job in my case. I don't wanted to see any open PopoverViewControllers on the screenshot. Only thing to take care is to do nothing animated when cleaning the screen, as this would take too long for the screenshot.

Comment: BTW, I was informed by an Apple engineer that the documentation re `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` is incorrect, that, as we all observed, a snapshot is actually taken, but simply won't be used at next launch.

Comment: ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch seems to do what it sounds like: prevent a screenshot from being displayed during application *launch*.  It doesn't affect the multitasking UI screenshot, or if your application is being resumed rather than launched.

Comment: @GlennMaynard Agreed. It does what the method name says (it won't use the snapshot on launch), not what the documentation says (that it won't take snapshot). Apple is reportedly planning on fixing the documentation.

Comment: Anyone facing an issue where the 1/10 chance the  self.passwordLabel is not hidden on iOS 11?

Answer (score 32):

This is the solution I worked with for my application:

As Tommy said: You can use the applicationWillResignActive. What I did was making a UIImageView with my SplashImage and add it as subview to my main window-

```
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Portrait(768x1024).png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
}
```

I used this method instead of applicationDidEnterBackground because applicationDidEnterBackground won't be triggered if you doubletap the home button, and applicationWillResignActive will be. I heard people say though it can be triggered in other cases aswell, so I'm still testing around to see if it gives problem, but none so far! ;)

Here to remove the imageview:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(imageView != nil) {
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        imageView = nil;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Sidenote: I tested this on both the simulator and a real device: It Won't Show on the simulator, but it does on a real device!

Comment: There is one drawback: applicationWillResignActive is called, amongst other cases, when the user pulls down the notifications dock. So you slide your finger from top downwards and see that image, while you've expected to see app contents.

Comment: It's better to blur sensitive information on applicationWillResignActive and set imageView on aplicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: This works, but there's a rotation bug when deployed to iOS7, built with xCode6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147068/xcode6-incorrect-view-controller-orientation-when-deployed-to-ios7-device

Comment: If I write code you mentioned in _applicationWillResignActive_, then what will I see when I bring my App back to foreground state ? Will I see "Portrait(768x1024).png" image or actual screen ?

Comment: @Pratik: You will see the image, unless you remove it again in the applicationDidBecomeActive method (see above).

Comment: There is one drawback, when app registers for push notifications, or a location alert is received, then also application goes into inactive state till the alert is closed, so the image view will be shown

Answer (score 15):

This quick and easy method will yield a black snapshot above your app's icon in the iOS7 or later app switcher.

First, take your app's key window (typically setup in AppDelegate.m in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), and hide it when your app is about to move into the background:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(isIOS7Or8)
    {
        self.window.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Then, un-hide your app's key window when your app becomes active again:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(isIOS7Or8)
    {
        self.window.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

At this point, check out the app switcher and verify that you see a black snapshot above your app's icon. I've noticed that if you launch the app switcher immediately after moving your app into the background, there can be a delay of ~5 seconds where you'll see a snapshot of your app (the one you want to hide!), after which it transitions to an all-black snapshot. I'm not sure what's up with the delay; if anyone has any suggestions, please chime in.

If you want a color other than black in the switcher, you could do something like this by adding a subview with any background color you'd like:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(isIOS7Or8)
    {
        UIView *colorView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame] autorelease];
        colorView.tag = 9999;
        colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        [self.window addSubview:colorView];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:colorView];
    }
}
```

Then, remove this color subview when your app becomes active again:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(isIOS7Or8)
    {
        UIView *colorView = [self.window viewWithTag:9999];
        [colorView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the following solution:
when application is going to resign I get appWindow snapshot as a View and add blur to it. Then I add this view to app window

how to do this:

1. in appDelegate just before implementation add line:

   ```
   static const int kNVSBlurViewTag = 198490;//or wherever number you like
   ```
2. add this methods:

   ```
   - (void)nvs_blurPresentedView
       {
           if ([self.window viewWithTag:kNVSBlurViewTag]){
               return;
           }
           [self.window addSubview:[self p_blurView]];
       }

       - (void)nvs_unblurPresentedView
       {
           [[self.window viewWithTag:kNVSBlurViewTag] removeFromSuperview];
       }

       #pragma mark - Private

       - (UIView *)p_blurView
       {
           UIView *snapshot = [self.window snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

           UIView *blurView = nil;
           if ([UIVisualEffectView class]){
               UIVisualEffectView *aView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
               blurView        = aView;
               blurView.frame  = snapshot.bounds;
               [snapshot addSubview:aView];
           }
           else {
               UIToolbar *toolBar  = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:snapshot.bounds];
               toolBar.barStyle    = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
               [snapshot addSubview:toolBar];
           }
           snapshot.tag = kNVSBlurViewTag;
           return snapshot;
       }
   ```
3. make your appDelegate implementation be the as follows:

   ```
   - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
       // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
       // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
       //...
       //your code
       //...

       [self nvs_blurPresentedView];
   }

       - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
       // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
       //...
       //your code
       //...

       [self nvs_unblurPresentedView];
   }
   ```

I created Example projects in [Swift](https://github.com/NikolayShubenkovProgSchool/BlurAppWindow-Swift) and [Objective C](https://github.com/NikolayShubenkovProgSchool/BlurAppWindow-ObjectiveC/tree/master). 
Both  projects makes the following actions in:

**-application:didResignActive** - snapshot is created, blurred and added to app window

**-application:willBecomeActive** blur view is being removed from window.

How to use:

**Objecitve C**

1. Add `AppDelegate+NVSBlurAppScreen` .h and .m files to your project
2. in your -applicationWillResignActive: method add the following line:

   ```
   [self nvs_blurPresentedView];
   ```
3. in your -applicationDidEnterBackground: method add the following line:

   ```
   [self nvs_unblurPresentedView];
   ```

**Swift**

1. add AppDelegateExtention.swift file to your project
2. in your applicationWillResignActive function add the following line:

   ```
   blurPresentedView()
   ```
3. in your applicationDidBecomeActive function add the following line:

   ```
   unblurPresentedView()
   ```

Answer (score 2):

if only use `[self.window addSubview:imageView];` in `applicationWillResignActive` function, This imageView won't cover UIAlertView, UIActionSheet or MFMailComposeViewController...

Best solution is

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
    [mainWindow addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: Very good solution if you have a video playing in fullscreen-mode in a webview!

Comment: Excellent!. It works even if we have a keypad open before getting into multitasking switcher! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Providing my own solution as an "answers", though this solution is very unreliable. Sometimes i get a black screen as the screenshot, sometimes the XIB and sometimes a screenshot from the app itself. Depending on device and/or if i run this in the simulator.

Please note i cannot provide any code for this solution since it's a lot of app-specific details in there. But this should explain the basic gist of my solution.

> In AppDelegate.m under applicationWillResignActive i check if we're
>   running iOS7, if we do i load a new view which is empty with the
>   app-logo in the middle. Once applicationDidBecomeActive is called i
>   re-launch my old views, which will be reset - but that works for the
>   type of application i'm developing.

Comment: If you see what the Camera app does - it transitions the image into a blurred one when going into the background (you can see the transition as it reduces to the icon)

Comment: @Petesh Yes, that's a nice implementation, but the question is how they do it. I fear a private API.

Comment: @Tommie You say "Depending on device and/or if i run this in the simulator". For me, it _appears_ to work on the device (though I haven't done exhaustive testing), but not the simulator. Are you finding it doesn't work on device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use activator to configure double clicking of home button to launch multitasking and disable default double clicking of home button and launching of multitasking window. This method can be used to change the screenshots to the application's default image. This is applicable to apps with default passcode protection feature.

Answer (score -2):

Xamarin.iOS

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040270/7561

Instead of just showing a color I wanted to show my launch screen.

```
 public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
 {
    //to add the background image in place of 'active' image
    var backgroundImage = new UIImageView();
    backgroundImage.Tag = 1234;
    backgroundImage.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Background");
    backgroundImage.Frame = this.window.Frame;
    this.window.AddSubview(backgroundImage);
    this.window.BringSubviewToFront(backgroundImage);
}

public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
{
    //remove 'background' image
    var backgroundView = this.window.ViewWithTag(1234);
    if(null != backgroundView)
        backgroundView.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```