# How can I present an viewController from Application window's rootViewController when user press home button, but before application enter background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that contains some sensitive information， I don't want others to snapshot the screen before app enter background, so I want to present a pattern lock viewController on the screen after user press home button. I tried this code

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
    PatternLockViewController *pvc = [[SMICConfig sharedSMICConfig] patternLockVC];
    if (!(pvc.isViewLoaded && pvc.view.window) && [SMICConfig sharedSMICConfig].isCookie)    {
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:NO completion:nil];
     }
}
```

But the PatternLockViewController only present after the app enter foreground. So, when the app stay in background, you can double-click home button to peek some information.

Tecent qq's pattern lock is very well. I just want to implement this effect.

Can any one help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tell iOS7 to avoid using the recent snapshot image during the next launch cycle by calling `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The following is how I implemented for my App. Hope it helps.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [application ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h"]];
    [self.window addSubview: self.imageView];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (self.imageView != nil) {
        [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
        self.imageView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch``` only available in iOS7 and later, if my target is ios 6 or before, is there a way to handle this problem?

Comment: iOS6 don't have multitasking :],and I think this is the [best question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18961652/2544997), thanks for your solution

Comment: My code work perfect with my physical device >_<