# Why doesn't my background color change onPause?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to change the color of the little "screenshot" the multitasking button seems to take/show when viewing the recent apps. I tried to do this by changing the color like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

This didn't work. With the code above, I can see that the color changes to blue, but the screen shot doesn't show blue. I thought if I put a little delay (This is totally purely conceptual. I know a user would be furious if you purposefully delayed leaving an activity) then the screenshot would show blue. So I did:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

But now I'm totally confused. The color doesn't turn blue at all until I go back into it. How is that possible? The change of color is clearly before the sleep().

Comment: Are you trying to hide your layout when the screen shot is taken or you really want the background to be blue?

Comment: Yous should change your code from OnPause to OnResume 
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: @joao2fast4u I'm trying to "hide" the screen shot, or change the color of it to black. I chose blue for this example. I'm trying to do this but for Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

Answer (score 0):

OK, according to what you explained in the comments, you can avoid the screenshot to show your layout, showing a black background instead, by setting the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`. This flag treats the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

To use it, call this inside your `Activity` `onCreate()`:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Note that you must call it before `setContentView()`.

Comment: Hrm... yes. I know that this is an option, but this also disables screen shots which is something I want enabled.

Comment: Hmmm...I understand, in that case you can exclude your activities from the recent apps screens by setting `android:excludeFromRecent` attribute for activities in AndroidManifest.xml.