# Delete cache folder when app enters background

Tags: ios, snapshot

I am using following code to delete a cache folder of my iOS app. It is working fine on simulator.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
  }];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier myId = bgTask;

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        static NSString *theCachesPath = nil; // Application caches path string
        NSArray *cachesPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        theCachesPath = [[cachesPaths objectAtIndex:0] copy]; //
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:theCachesPath error:NULL]; /// remove cache
        [application endBackgroundTask:myId];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
  });
}
```

The problem is that, when on device, I press home button, the app snapshot (which gets stored in cache folder) should be deleted but its not happening.

Please help.

Comment: So you want the cache deleted when you press the home button while being in the app, that will lead in taking the back to the background?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to disable the app snapshot you could change the screenshot that is being taken to a blank screen or obscure the sensitive data that is being stored manually, or if it is an enterprise app you can stop them all together.

This was answered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18961652/2969035