# iOS7 how to programmatically show black screen for iPhone multitasking screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, multitasking, application-lifecycle

I'm working on a medical app and would like to prevent any information about the user from being saved onto the multitasking screen.

Some apps, like Bank of America show black screen for the app when the user toggles multitasking mode (double tap home). **Is there  away for me to get my app to show black on multitasking screen, regardless of how the app was terminated?**

Maybe there is an xCode plist option to exclude app's screenshot from being saved into multitasking menu?

Will monitoring App Delegate's lifestyle events and replacing the topmost screen with black be enough to guarantee no info being saved to multitasking screen?

Bank of America will show a black screen in the middle below:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the answer can be found here. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

Comment: add the blackscreen in this method under appdelegate.   - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application or   - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch) you can prevent snapshots being taken using `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`:

> If you feel that the snapshot cannot correctly reflect your app’s user interface when your app is relaunched, you can call [ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch] to prevent that snapshot image from being taken.

Comment: These snapshots are only shown when the app is launched and do not affect the multitasking screenshot. To change those, it seems that as Bejibun suggested, I need to monitor app lifecycle events