# VC's view still present after invalidation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a pretty simple VC hierarchy where the application's window has a rootVC navigation controller and that has its viewcontrollers in a stack.

The requirement is that when the user goes to background (lock button or home button), the VC hierarchy should be "thrown to the bin" so that we start over and rebuild it (inside )when entered foreground next time.

In appDelegate in  applicationDidEnterBackground handler I am doing this

```
UIViewController *yellowVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
yellowVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers = @[yellowVC];
```

However, when going foreground again, for some reason I see the contents of previous topmost controller for a second or so.

Why is that? AFAIK It was deallocated when I replaced the viewControllers array.

Is this some screenshot the OS is making? I find it hard to believe it is the topmost VC still alive.

How to get rid of that annoyance?

BTW. it is iOS 7.1 and simulator.

Comment: try to look into this instead of creating custom yellow layer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

Comment: The simulator behaves differently from the device for this feature. I've built similar previously and wasted lots of time because of this.

Comment: Additionally, it is a screenshot being captured and displayed. You'll need to dismiss the VC stack sooner.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you can quit completely your app on exit ?

Open your info.plist file

Add The Key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` or Select `Application does not run in background`

Set the new key to `YES` or Fill in the tick box

Comment: Apples discourages you from calling exit anywhere in the application.