# xCode6 incorrect view controller orientation when deployed to iOS7 device

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, orientation, xcode6

I'm running into a weird issue when testing an app with deployment target of 7.1 compiled with xCode6 and tested on an iOS 7.1.2 and iOS 8.0.2 devices.

A view controller is defined in storyboard with a portrait placeholder. The app supports landscape orientation only.

in app delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIViewController* privacyScreen;
self.privacyScreen = [kMainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privacyScreen"];
[self.window addSubview:self.privacyScreen.view];
```

When deployed to **iOS8**, the status bar is in **landscape** and the view controller is in **landscape**.
When deployed to **iOS 7.1**, the status bar is in **landscape**, but the view controller is in **portrait**

**How can I make sure my view controllers are in the expected orientation, regardless of which iOS they run on?** For example, I would expect to have no portrait view controllers if my app does not support portrait in the project settings.