# iOS caches the application screen when clicking the home button for the device

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

we are developing hybrid application on Worklight.
After the user launches the application on iOS, he will see the login screen, providing his credentials, he is inside our application.

Now, if the user clicked the home button for iOS before "logging out" from the app, the iOS will take a snapshot and store it inside the device cache.

By using IExplorer, I can see this screen cached, which in our situation a high critical issue.

How can I a override this screen with a white screen, in case the user clicked the home button of the iOS device it will be populated immediately, and the device will not snapshot the user main screen.?

Is there any thumbnail I can add to my nativeResource folder for iOS to solve this issue?

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to look at the Worklight Knowledge Center. In most cases, you **will** find your answer.

To control the snapshot taken by the OS when moving to the background, you need to use [the following API methods](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.BackgroundHandler.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-3), depending on your needs:

`WL.App.BackgroundHandler.setOnAppEnteringBackground` and `WL.App.BackgroundHandler.setOnAppEnteringForeground`

Comment: would you please tell me where to implement these two calls? in which js? Where should I code this part "
WL.App.BackgroundHandler.setOnAppEnteringBackground(
WL.App.BackgroundHandler.hideView
);". thanks.

Comment: You can put it in wlCommonInit.