# Blur the image in image view at Background iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode-6.2

I want to  place the image view on background of window,above the image view i have placed the table view which is transparent.I want image in background is to be blur. thanks..

Comment: Does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher) help?

Comment: thanks but i want fully blurred image for that view

Comment: Do you have any more info or a sketch of what you're asking? This would help get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8 you can use UIVisualEffect to blur views

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];// explore other effects too
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView =[[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = YOURFRAME; // set frame
[visualEffectView setAlpha:1.0];// set as you like
[YOURVIEW addSubview:visualEffectView]; //add on your view where you want
```