# Is UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend the same as exit(0)?

Tags: ios, plist

I want to present a lock screen if TouchID/Pascode is set in my applications settings. I want it to work similar to Dropbox and 1Password where if you have this set, and then you press the Home button on the iPhone, if you reopen the app it automatically **shows the lock screen and displays Touch ID alert.**

For my app I want a similar behavior. In Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial on security](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password), they set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (also known as "Application does not run in background") to YES in the pList. The problem for me is that I don't want this set at all times - **for my app it should only be set if Touch ID/Passcode is enabled by the user in my applications settings.** So my concern is:

- Can I set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend programmatically in code?
- If not, can I use exit(0) or exit(1)? I seen **many** stack overflow pages where they say not do this --- but I will only call this in applicationDidEnterBackground if Touch ID/Passcode is enabled by the user in my applications settings.

I want to launch this app to the app store as well. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to exit your app to show a lock screen on the next use?

Comment: @rmaddy If it's not done this way, then it looks bad when the user enters the app again. For example, when the user presses the Home button, iOS saves the screen the user was on, then when the user opens the app again, the old screen iOS saved is shown first, then finally my Lock Screen is showed after about 1 second. This isn't a good experience. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are existing topics on how to deal with this. Essentially you add code that results in the saved screen shot being blank. This ensures that sensitive data isn't briefly shown before the lock screen is displayed.

Comment: @rmaddy Any links you could send in Swift? Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any specific to Swift. Just add a blank screen in the app delegate method when entering the background and remove it when entering the foreground.

Comment: @rmaddy anything in Objective-C? I'll just convert it. Sorry I'm a beginner -- I'm trying to think of how to do this but not sure as of now.

Comment: Here's a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks!!! I'll look into it.