# greying out the view controller if the application did enter background

Tags: ios

I have built an ios application that is quite data sensitive, if the user exit the app, I need to make sure the input data are all gone. for example , if the user keying in the username and password, and exit the app, it need to empty out the fields so that after user enter again he will have to reenter data. The problem now is the login view controller is in swift , while the app delegate is in objective c. how should i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher)

Comment: What is your actual issue? Simply have you login controller reset its input fields when the app returns from the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods
precisely the `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;` will be called when the app is going into the background ( user clicks the home button)

Find the documentation on this page [applicationDidEnterBackground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground?language=objc)